# Why use *//<![CDATA[* and *//]]>* in a jQuery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this working piece of javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#page_template option[value='sidebar-page.php']").remove();
        });
    //]]>
</script>
```

What's `//<![CDATA[` and `//]]>` stand for? I never used it but lately I meet it very often.
Thank you guys in advance for increasing my knowledge! ;)

Comment: The CDATA tags here have been commented out, so surely they would have no effect here? So I don't understand why this question has been marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CDATA is used to allow the document to be loaded as straight XML. You can embed [JS in XML  documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Writing_JavaScript_for_XHTML) without replacing special XML characters like <, >, &, etc by XML entities &lt;, &gt;, &amp; etc to prevent that the XML syntax get corrupted.

So `double slash //` in your XML will be treated as text instead of a comment and hence it makes CDATA as an XML tag.

The **wiki** says that:-

> In an XML document or external parsed entity, a CDATA section is a
>   section of element content that is marked for the parser to interpret
>   as only character data, not markup. A CDATA section is merely an
>   alternative syntax for expressing character data; there is no semantic
>   difference between character data that manifests as a CDATA section
>   and character data that manifests as in the usual syntax in which <
>   and & would be represented by < and &, respectively.

Comment: Fixed your entities for you ;)

Comment: Yes. but the asker wants to know about these tags which have been commented out using double slashes. Surely these tags would then have no effect?